# 90s-2000s cartoon about an alien who is stranded on Earth and has a son with a woman

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was this 90s-2000s TV cartoon show (like the old-style cartoons *X-Men*, *Spider-Man*, *Superman* etc) about an alien being stranded on Earth and fathering a child with a woman. Then something happened to the woman I think (not sure though I don’t remember it); the boy grew up and they were at war with the aliens (I think) and he found out his father was an alien, and it was kinda them-against-the-world things.

It happened in a dystopian world, I think that the first episode happened like the woman enters in a cave after the alien (who looked like human and had the appearance of a human, he had the haircut similar to Gaston from *Beauty and the Beast*), and the guy says something like "people are chasing me" he probably was hurt, and then she sits with him and they get really close and sleep together.
And I think the alien really loved the kid's mom too, he didn't stay in their lives for their own safety and only came for him when the mom was gone.

It was a Western cartoon, not Japanese.

That's all I can remember, because I was really young at the time, maybe 6-7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it: [*Invasion America*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_America) (1998):

> The story of *Invasion America* begins in the early 1980s, when humanoid aliens from the planet Tyrus begin to initiate their plans for making contact with Earth. Cale-Oosha, the ruler of Tyrus, looks into his uncle's project with Earth. However, his uncle, The Dragit, claims that their dying planet ought to invade Earth and take hold of its resources. Cale refuses, and a civil war breaks out.
>
> Cale and Rafe, his bodyguard, trainer, and trusted friend, escape to Earth, disguising themselves as humans. Cale meets Rita Carter, a human woman; he falls in love with her, and they marry. After a long time of running from the Dragit's forces on Earth, Cale returns to Tyrus to help strengthen his loyalist forces, the Ooshati, leaving Rita and their young son, David, under Rafe's protection.
>
> In the present day, when the Dragit finally finds the family, he is determined to kill them, and David Carter's teenage life is thrown into a devastating adventure of stopping the Dragit, losing and gaining friends, and finding out just who he is.